# iOS UITableView - Show delete button upon both swipe left and click cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and also implemented the logic to swipe to show the delete button, as such:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return YES;
} 

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViefw commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete {
         //logic to delete...
     }
}
```

However, I need a way for the delete button to also show up when the user clicks on a table cell. Is that possible?

I've seen other answers that suggest using `[tableView setEditing: true]`, but that also shows the red icon on the left and I don't want that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you subclass `UITabeViewCell`, then you can use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method to get the clicked cell, you can then show a delete button (whatever design you want), and when that is clicked the cell gets deleted front the datasource and the tableView gets updated, whether there is a framework way of doing it, I do not know.

But good luck anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method..

- When deleting a row you must remove that data form your `array`. After that you need to reload `tableview` again to show the updated `tableview`

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
      Your_tableview.editing=YES;

      [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

---

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSLog(@"Delete Success");
        [Your_Array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.Your_tableView reloadData]
    }
    else
    {
         NSLog(@"Delete Canceled");
    }

}
```